# How can I compile cppcheck.exe

Tags: clang, cross-compiling, cppcheck

I changed the source code of cppcheck, and I can use "make && make install" to compile cppcheck in Linux. I don't know how to compile cppcheck.exe so that it can be run in the Windows dos cmd window?

Comment: Please add the code changes you made or a file example to allow help.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be satisfied with a `cppcheck` executable that runs in a unix-like environment in Windows? If so, you could install Cygwin, or the Windows Subsystem for Linux. In either of those environments, you can use the same `make` commands you used in Linux.

If you want a true native Windows executable, the simplest way is probably to use Microsoft Visual Studio. The `cppcheck` source code comes with a `cppcheck.sln` solution file in the top-level directory, which Visual Studio should be able to use to produce an executable.

In addition, if you want to produce a Windows installer, there is a `win_installer` subdirectory which itself contains a solution file for building the installer. You'll want to read `win_installer/readme.txt` and make sure you have all the necessary tools to make this work.

Finally, if your changes to `cppcheck` would be useful to others, please be sure to send a pull-request back to the main `cppcheck` [repository](https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck).